# exact phrase search by a single column filter in datatables

Tags: ajax, filter, datatables, cpu-word

I am using datatables in my php code to filter column by using selectbox. In jquery.dataTables.js, one piece of code of there like:

```
/* Single column filter */
$.extend( oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iColumn ], {
    "sSearch": sInput+"",
    "bRegex": bRegex,
    "bSmart": bSmart,
    "bCaseInsensitive": bCaseInsensitive
} );
_fnFilterComplete( oSettings, oSettings.oPreviousSearch, 1 );
```

In my case I have a column which contains `BM`, `ISM`, `TL` and `ABM` values. Now whenever I am searching the columns by `BM`, I got `BM` as well as `ABM` records. But it should be only `BM` records.
I have modified the above code to :

```
/* Single column filter */
    $.extend( oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iColumn ], {
        "sSearch": sInput+"",
        "bRegex": false,
        "bSmart": false,
        "bCaseInsensitive": false
    } );
    _fnFilterComplete( oSettings, oSettings.oPreviousSearch, 1 );
```

But still it is not working. So please help me how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why is there a "php" tag?

Comment: because this is integrating with php code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing in the jquery.dataTables.js, change in the page where datatables is declared and defining.  Change to

```
$('select', this).change( function () {
            if($(this).val() != ''){
                oTable.fnFilter( "(^|\s)"+$(this).val()+"(\s|$)", i ,true); //filter exact word
            }else{
                oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use your own regular expression,remember to disable both regx  and smart filtering

```
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iColumn ], {
        "sSearch": "^\\s*"+sInput+"\\s*$",
        "bRegex": false,
        "bSmart": false,
        "bCaseInsensitive": false
    }
```